# Не подгружает фотографии Яндекс картах в WebView java fx

Tags: java, javafx, webview

Есть метод в контроллере:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    WebEngine webEngine = yaMapWeb.getEngine();
    webEngine.load(getClass().getResource("/com/example/demo/yaMap.html").toExternalForm());
}
```

}
Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Магазины по близости</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=@@@&lang=ru_RU" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    ymaps.ready(init);
    var myMap,
        myPlacemark;

    function init(){
        myMap = new ymaps.Map ("map", {
            center: [58.01, 56.19],
            zoom: 7
        });

        myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.76, 37.64], {
            hintContent: 'Пермь!',
            balloonContent: 'Город Пермь, Россия'
        });

        myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
    }
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

При загрузке формы у меня выводится карта, но смотрите как она выводится:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если html вставить в браузер, то все работает и подгружает, пробовал гугл выводить(поисковик, а не карту), все работает, но именно фотографии не подгружает(Даже логотип гугла не подгружает)

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо было обновить зависимости в pom.xml